# How to fix the batch size in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Basically, I want to write a loss function that computes scores comparing the labels and output of the batch. For, this I need to fix the batch size.

I previously did it in Tensorflow where I could set the batch size in the placeholder function. Now, I need to use similar mechanism in a Keras code which was provided to me. I don't know how to do it here.

```py
conv1 = (Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], activation='elu'))(input_img)
print(conv1.shape)
```

The output of the print statement is obviously `[?, 32, 32, 3]`.
How do I make it, say `[64, 32, 32, 3]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `keras.layers.Input` layer to specify the batch size:

```py
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input
from keras import regularizers

x = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3), batch_size=64)
conv1 = Conv2D(filters=32,
               kernel_size=(3,3),
               padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1.),
               input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
               activation='elu')(x)
print(conv1.shape) # (64, 32, 32, 32)
```

Comment: I had to use, x = Input(batch_shape=(64,32,32,3)). Thanks a lot.